# Select and copy a content from a website

Tags: php

Im trying to extract a part of my website to get some content information. The content of that I'm trying to put into a variable is like:

```
 <table  class="tabelaHistorico">
              <tr> 
                <td bgcolor=#ccccc></td>
                <td bgcolor=#ccccc>2014</td>
              </tr>

              <tr> 
                <td> 
                  Jan
                </td>
                <td> 
                  9719,46
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr> 
                <td> 
                  Fev
                </td>
                <td> 
                  9421,65
                </td>
              </tr>
  </table>
```

I tried to do:

```
 $content = file_get_contents("www.website.com");
 $pos = strpos($content,"table" , 0);
 echo $pos;
 printf($pos);
 $rest = substr($content, $pos, 5);
 echo $rest;
```

Comment: Your example will get the first 5 characters after the word 'table', which in this case would be `  cla`. I suspect you need DOMDocument as @ceejayoz suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a proper HTML parser. Luckily, PHP has one built-in.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: @user3813186 We're not going to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('!<table  class="tabelaHistorico">.+?</table>!s', $content, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Comment: But if I do that, It wont work, I want to get without <tr> and <td>

Comment: echo strip_tags($match[0]);